# forecolor of a listview subitem doesn't stay

Tags: c#, listview

I set the ForeColor of a Subitem in my ListView, but when I move with the Mouse over the Item, the Color changes back.

I don't want to check/set the color new in the MousMove Event.
Any idea to set the color 'forever'?
Thanks

```
foreach (var key in list)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(key);
    item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
    if (!Directory.Exists(key)) item.SubItems[0].ForeColor = Color.Red;
    lvDirs.Items.Add(item);
    item.SubItems.Add("");
    item.SubItems.Add("...");
}
```

Comment: Does the color change back only until you move the mouse cursor away, or does it revert permanently?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. The `ForeColor` of the subitem is changed to `White` (by default) only when we set `FullRowSelect=true` and select the row, otherwise its forecolor is what we set.

Comment: BTW, where is your snippet of code above in your whole code?

Comment: @King King
The code above is called in the constructor of the form, after this:
`InitializeComponent();

            ListViewExtender extender = new ListViewExtender(lvDirs);
            ListViewButtonColumn buttonAction = new ListViewButtonColumn(2);
            buttonAction.Click += new EventHandler<ListViewColumnMouseEventArgs>(buttonAction_Click);
            buttonAction.FixedWidth = true;

            extender.AddColumn(buttonAction);`

Comment: @Bobson
The color changes, when the mouse moves the first time above the row (fullrowselect is set to true) and sometimes, when the form/listview refreshes, the color is set to red again.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes around with the extender? In its MouseMove event the listview calls Invalidate(item.bounds); But how can I say there the color not to change?